# Wijmo grid and knockout observableArray bound to data option not working for me

Tags: knockout.js, wijmo

The wijmo grid setup to get its data from a knockout observableArray in the following fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/t316/K3GMR/7/ is not initializing itself properly, i.e. you see no grid.

This is happening because of an error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Object function d(){if(0<arguments.length){if(!d.equalityComparer||!d.equalityComparer(c,arguments[0]))d.H(),c=arguments[0],d.G();return this}b.r.Wa(d);return c} has no method 'load' "
```

Wijmo grid is supposed to be able be bound to a knockout observableArray in the manner I am trying, is it not?  Why is the grid not initializing properly and not showing the small sample data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the correct way of binding a wijgrid with KO observable array. The following code goes into the script section:

```
    var viewModel = {
        data: ko.observableArray([
          { "Name": "a" },
          { "Name": "b" }
        ])
    };

    //Bind ViewModel
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
```

The HTML table can be defined like below:

```
<table id="dataGrid" data-bind="wijgrid: { data: data, columns : [ { headerText : 'Name'}],
    ensureControl : true} ">
</table>
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thank you for that. This did indeed solve my problem. Two quick questions: 1) installing wijmo from nuget installs 2.4.1 – that’s where I got my outdated wijmo from.  Am I doing something wrong? 2) I originally started my sample the mvvm way and couldn't get it to work – I prefer the mvvm way, but out of curiosity can you not bind to an observablearray with the jquery plugin initialization way, using data: … option?